# How would I print the JVM's system properties using Java 8 and lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

You can obtain a `Properties` instance of the JVM properties using [`System.getProperties()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--); how would you go about using Java 8 code to print all properties to the console?

Comment: Nobody should be running JDK 8 anymore.  You need to upgrade to LTS version JDK 17 immediately.

Answer (score 8):

One solution:

```
public final class Foo
{
    private static void printProperty(final Object key, final Object value)
    {
        System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        System.getProperties().forEach(Foo::printProperty);
    }
}
```

Rundown:

- `Properties` extends `Hashtable<Object, Object>` which itself implements `Map<Object, Object>`;
- `Map` has a [`.forEach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method whose argument is a [`BiConsumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html);
- `BiConsumer` is a [functional interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html);
- static method `printProperty()` of class `Foo` happens to have the same signature as a `BiConsumer<Object, Object>`: its "return value" is `void`, its first argument is `Object`, its second argument is `Object`;
- we can therefore use `Foo::printProperty` as a method reference.

A shorter version would be:

```
public final class ShorterFoo
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        System.getProperties()
            .forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
    }
}
```

At runtime, this would not make a difference. Note the type inference in the second example: the compiler can infer that `key` and `value` are of type `Object`. Another way to write this "anonymous lambda" would have been:

```
(Object key, Object value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value)
```

---

(not so) Side note: even though it is a little outdated, you really want to watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_QbkGU_lqY) (yes, it's one hour long; yes, it is worth watching it all).

---

(not so) Side note 2: you may have noticed that [`Map`'s `.forEach()` mentions a default implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-); this means that your custom `Map` implementations, or other implementations from external libraries, will be able to use `.forEach()` (for instance, Guava's `ImmutableMap`s). Many such methods on Java collections exist; do not hesitate to use these "new methods" on "old dogs".

Comment: What do you mean by "(not so)"?

Comment: @KirkWoll sort of a pun; that is, I deem these side notes as important as the answer itself

Answer (score 5):

@fge has missed one very short version that admittedly depends on the `toString` implementation of `Map.Entry`.

```
public class VeryShortFoo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.getProperties().entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

- Here, the `entrySet` is streamed and each `Map.Entry` is printed with a reference to `out.println`.
- `Map.Entry` implementations of `toString` generally return `getKey() + "=" + getValue()`.

Here's another one I quite like.

```
public class ElegantFoo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.getProperties().entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

- The `entrySet` is streamed again (this time explicitly with a call to `stream`).
- [`Stream#map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) performs a 1:1 conversion from elements of one type to elements of another. Here, it turns a `Stream<Map.Entry>` in to a `Stream<String>`.
- The `Stream<String>` is printed.

Comment: Nice one... In fact I haven't even tried that. Of note here is that it really "calls" the `.forEach()` method on a `Set`. (also, pure English question: wouldn't you write "admittedly" instead of "admittingly"?)

Comment: Might I suggest that you highlight the "rundown" of your code snippets like I did?

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, the `Properties` class inherits a new method from `HashTable` called `forEach`. This new method accepts functions (*functional interfaces*) to be passed to it as arguments. To be more specific, it accepts the functional interface `BiConsumer<T,U>`. This functional interface's *functional method* is `accept(T t, U u)`. In Java 8, all functional interfaces can be written as Lambda expressions. Therefore, here is how we would display all properties in a `Property` instance:

```
Properties vmProps = System.getProperties();
vmProps.forEach((t,u) -> System.out.println("Property: " + t + "\nValue: " + u + "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorted** by key using a TreeSet. This makes the output easier to read.

```
printMap(System.getProperties());
printMap(System.getenv());

public static void printMap(Map properties) {
    new TreeSet<>(properties.keySet()).forEach((k) -> {
        System.out.println(k + " : " + properties.get(k));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.getProperties().keySet().forEach((k)-> System.out.println(k + "   ::::   "+ System.getProperty(k.toString())) );

    }
```

Shortest Version for me :D
The following for System Variables

```
System.getenv().forEach((String env, String val) -> System.out.println(new StringBuilder(env).append("  =>>  ").append(val).toString()));
```