# Eclipse not reading System.getenv() correctly - PATH missing elements

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

If I run `echo $PATH`, I get:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Amongst others.

If I make a simple application that does the same:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getenv().get("PATH"));
    }
}
```

When I run this from the console (`java -jar test.jar`):

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

And yet when I run that same application in Eclipse:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Why isn't Eclipse picking up all the environment variables?

Comment: Is the java process behind Eclipse running as the same user?

Comment: @g00se yes, both are running under my user account (verified in `Activity Monitor` using PID).

Comment: Applications like Eclipse don't get the path set up for Terminal. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/2670892) for lots of discussion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment variables in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048216/environment-variables-in-eclipse)

Comment: @aled no - I don't want to manually copy my `$PATH` to my IDE, and that's not portable.

Comment: By default, applications are launched from within Eclipse without any environment variables set (for reasons of portability).  [If you want to pass or local environment variable `PATH` to your application, in your launch configuration in the tab _Environment_ set `PATH` to `${env_var:PATH}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698254/6505250).

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Linux. I would try:

**Understanding environment variables**

If you run java from your console it executes in the context of the current console session.

1. If you change `$PATH` in your current session it doesn´t mean that the value is available system wide. e.g. when you start a different session (eclipse) the content of the variable can differ.
2. Different shells behave differently depending on where you have defined your variables. e.g  ~/.profile is only loaded when running zsh in sh compatibility mode, otherwise it reads .zprofile, as well as .zshrc for interactive and .zlogin for login shells.

Eclipse might have problems with `env` vars on the user level.
See: [Eclipse and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048245/1485527)
See: [Zsh invocation order](https://superuser.com/questions/457889/order-of-execution-and-purpose-of-profile-vs-zshrc)

**Persist $PATH**

This is typically done by initializing the variable during logging via a config file on **user** or **system level**. For macos see [Setting PATH environment variable in OSX permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently) .

**Logout and login again**

After adding the variable to the system configuration you have to logout and login again to make its contents available through all sessions.

**Verify user**

If the `$PATH` is persistent it should be the same in all console sessions. Print `System.getProperty("user.name");` to verify that the expected user is calling `java -jar`. [1]

[1] [Howto print all environment vars and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54781548/1485527)

Comment: I haven't changed the `$PATH` in this session, and a reboot hasn't helped.

Comment: Where do you set the $PATH? If you use `.bashrc` or some other user specific profile config it might be ignored by eclipse, like stated here: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048245/1485527 .

Comment: Also see: https://superuser.com/questions/457889/order-of-execution-and-purpose-of-profile-vs-zshrc